# Jsfiddle in Key Map: Vim Mode. Is there a shortcut to switch between editor textarea

Tags: vim, jsfiddle

I love jsfiddle so much. Recently I found out they even allow using it in Vim mode.

All my favorite short-cut keyboards are there except for switching between the editor textarea. Usually in Vim I would use ctrl + w to switch. But when I use it in JSfiddle, it will terminate my browser tab.

I have search for this in google but cannot find any solution. If there is any, please help me. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Judging by the code, Ctrl+Down should be "switch to next view" and Ctrl+Up should be "switch to previous view" but neither seem to work, here. FWIW, of the defined shortcuts, only Ctrl+Enter for "run", Ctrl+Shift+Enter for "load draft" and Ctrl+S for "save and reload" work here.

Comment: I'm using google chrome while using jsfiddle. Could it be because of it, that this function Ctrl + Down does not work ?

Comment: Same behavior on Firefox..